# Python: How to identify a class using a label?

Tags: python, class, oop

The code I am working on has a class called *cell*, an object which carries a label attribute. The snippet of code looks as follows:

```
class Cell:
  def init(self, label):
    self.label = label
```

Later in the code I have a list of cell objects, each of them carrying a unique label.
Is there way to, given a specific label, find the corresponding cell object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick the right one by label, why do not you create a dictoinary of cells instead of a list? Then it is easy to extract the wished one: `mycell = cell_d['wished_label']`. But otherwise it is not too complicated either:

```
for cell in cell_list:
    if cell.label == 'wished_label':
        mycell = cell
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! Is using a dictionary faster than iterating over the cell_list? Or slower? Or doesn't it matter? I was wondering if it is possible to do this without iterating over the whole list (as the list is large).

Comment: With a dictionary, indeed, you do not need to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You could elaborate your Cell class to facilitate an index search. Something like this:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.label == other
        if isinstance(other, Cell):
            return self.label == other.label
        return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

cell_list = [Cell('H'), Cell('O')]

print(cell_list.index(Cell('O')))
print(cell_list.index('H'))
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
```

**Note:**

As with any other list index operation, if an item is not found, ValueError will be raised